# zend framework conflicting with codeigniter

Tags: zend-framework, codeigniter, php, include-path

First I should say I'm very new to php and linux admin.

For a previous site zend we installed on our production machine. We've decided to move off of zend and use codeigniter. However, once I pushed the site to production from local for testing I am getting errors stating that:

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'codeigniter/application/models/vo/navItemVO.php' (include_path='.:/var/www/html/ZendFramework-1.5.2/library') in /var/www/html/staging/echo/website/codeigniter/application/models/wordpresshook_model.php  on line 9

I am assuming that the server is going to Zend to call it's functions vs going to codeigniter. Is there anyway to disable or turn off Zend in .htaccess. I see blog entries or disabling the optimizer "php_value zend_optimizer.optimization_level=  0" but this doesn't seem to be working.

I'm open to any other options, but I can't turn this off at the root level in php.ini

Thanks in advance!!!!
Lori-

Answer (score 3):

I don't really know CI but it looks like you need to configure your include path to the CI library files.

You can configure this server wide in the `php.ini` file or set it in your application's bootstrap / startup script using something like

```
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    '/path/to/codeigniter/lib',
    get_include_path()
)));
```

Comment: Thanks!! Of course after spending HOURS! HOURS!! I say i figured this out and of course it was something so simple.  Your are totally right. I just needed to update the include_path to point to the right directory...